# How to write generic group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code, Only difference is way it groups data, Is there any way to make this into one logic by passing group by arguments, So the duplicate code can be removed.

```
  public interface IStackChartData
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting);
}

public class DailyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Hour, x.RateId })
                                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                             cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                             cl.Key.Hour.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                             cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                             chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
    }
}

public class MonthlyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Date, x.RateId })
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                  cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                  cl.Key.Date.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                  cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                  chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
    }
}

public class YearlyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Month, x.RateId })
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                                  cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                                  cl.Key.Month.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                                  cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                                  chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x.DataTime` is a `DateTime`, the only thing different between your implementations is that you might have an `int Month`, `int Hour`, or `DateTime Date` as your unit of time. You need to call that culture-sensitive conversion, which is conveniently part of an interface, `IConvertible`. So you can write one `static` method with a `Func` to select this piece of data:

```
internal static IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting, Func<DateTime, IConvertible> selector)
{
    return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { TimeUnit=selector(x.DataTime), x.RateId })
                                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                         cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                         cl.Key.TimeUnit.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                         cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                         chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
}
```

And then calling becomes simple:

```
public class DailyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return MyUtilities.GetDetails(chartSetting, x => x.Hour);
    }
}

public class MonthlyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return MyUtilities.GetDetails(chartSetting, x => x.Date);
    }
}

public class YearlyStack : IStackChartData
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return MyUtilities.GetDetails(chartSetting, x => x.Month);
    }
}
```